# Add a variable with quotes to string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is probably stupid simple, but I can't figure it out.

I am building a string in javascript

```
var template = '<div class="big-long-string-here">';
```

Now that works fine, but say I wanted to use `ng-class` with this div.

```
var template = '<div class="big-long-string-here" ng-class="{'open' : navCollapsed}">
```

Now, I'm escaping the string to place my class name, open in the string.

How would I pass this properly so it's rendered correctly in the DOM?

Comment: You could review whether it's appropriate to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in your project.

Comment: Is `open`  a variable whose value is supposed to be substituted into the string?

Comment: No, open should quite literally read 'open'

Answer (score 2):

Use string concatenation.

```
var template = '<div class="big-long-string-here" ng-class="{' + open + ' : navCollapsed}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literal

```
var template = `<div class="big-long-string-here" ng-class='{"open" : "navCollapsed"}'>`;
```

If `navCollapsed` is a variable identifier

```
var template = `<div class="big-long-string-here" ng-class='{"open" : ${navCollapsed}}'>`;
```

Comment: I feel like your second solution is closest. However I need to be able to toggle the navCollapsed between true and false by clicking a button later on. That solution sets an indefinite value.

Comment: @user7366018 Not sure what you mean? You can change the attribute and the value of `navCollapse` at any time

Comment: It's sending this to the dom: `ng-class="{"open" : false}"`

Comment: That is not valid `html` for an attribute. If single quotes are used to surround value of attribute double quotes can be used inside of `.value` of attribute. Double quotes should not appear within double quotes of attribute value. What do you mean by "That solution sets an indefinite value"?

Comment: Once it's set to false, it can't be changed.

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't be changed"? Why cannot the attribute be changed? How can you "toggle" the attribute value if the attribute value cannot be changed?

Comment: Note, the actual Question presented at OP is _"How would I pass this properly so it's rendered correctly in the DOM?"_ Not how to "toggle" element attribute value. Use single quotes to surround attribute value where double quotes appear within text of attribute value itself. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```js
$templateCache.put('udt-toolbar.html', '<div ng-class="{{datatable.config.name ? \'your-class\' : \' \'}}" name="udt-toolbar" class="button-toolbar-main clearfix"></div>');
```

This is how can be resolved.